# Shorten the code for a lot of buttons in Prototype

Tags: javascript, button, prototypejs, mouseevent

I have a lot of buttons and by clicking on different button, different image and text would appear. I can achieve what I want, but the code is just so long and it seems very repetitive.
For example:

```
   var aaClick = false;
    $("aa").observe('click', function() {
        unclick();
        $('characterPic').writeAttribute('src',"aa.jpg");
        $('characterBio').update("aatext");
        $('aa').setStyle({ color: '#FFFFFF' });
        aaClick = true;
    });

    $("aa").observe('mouseover', function() {
        if (!aaClick) $('aa').setStyle({ color: '#FFFFFF' });
    });

    $("aa").observe('mouseout', function() {
        if (!aaClick) $('aa').setStyle({ color: '#666666' });
    });

    function unclick() {
         aaClick = false;
         $('aa').setStyle({ color: '#666666' });
    }
```

same thing with bb, cc, etc. and every time I add a new button, I need to add it to unclick function as well. This is pretty annoying and I tried to google it, and I only found observe click on all listed items, so I still couldn't figure out since what I want involves button up when other buttons are clicked.

Is there any way to just have a generic function that takes different id but do the exact same thing? Because from what I can see, if I can just replace aa with other id, I can reduce a lot of code. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build it all into a function where you can simply pass it the names of the DIVs you want to register. As long are you are consistent with your .jpg names, it should work.

```
var clicks = []
function regEvents(divName) {
    $(divName).observe('click', function() {
        unclick(divName);
        $('characterPic').writeAttribute('src',divName+".jpg");
        $('characterBio').update(divName"text");
        $(divName).setStyle({ color: '#FFFFFF' });
        clicks[divName] = true

    });

    $(divName).observe('mouseover', function() {
        if (!clicks[divName]) $(divName).setStyle({ color: '#FFFFFF' });
    });

    $(divName).observe('mouseout', function() {
        if (!clicks[divName]) $(divName).setStyle({ color: '#666666' });
    });
}
function unclick(divName) {
     clicks[divName] = false;
     $(clicks[divName]).setStyle({ color: '#666666' });
}
```

Comment: this is a very oldie but a goodie.  I think it's been around since the dawn of DHTML

Comment: i have a very dumb question, how should I call it? I mean this will be in another js file, how do I call it from my html file? thanks again.

Comment: call it with: regEvents('aa')

Comment: I kept is pretty simple to follow since you're new to this stuff. There are shorter ways to do it, but they are more difficult to understand and follow.

Comment: i'm sorry but where exactly should I put regEvents('aa')? I tried to put it in <li><a href = "#" onclick = "regEvents('aa')">aa</a></li> but it doesnt work and I have no idea where else can I put it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Event delegation. Give all your buttons a class (eg `yourButtonClass`), then...

```
var clicks = [];
$$('.yourButtonClass').each(function(button) {
    clicks.push(button.id);
});
$(document).observe('click', function(e) {
    // If your click registered on an element contained by the button, this comes in handy...
    var clicked = e.element().up('.yourButtonClass') || e.element();

    if(clicked.hasClassName('.yourButtonClass')) {
        unclick();
        $('characterPic').writeAttribute('src', clicked.id + '.jpg');
        $('characterBio').update(clicked.id + 'text');
        $(clicked).setStyle({ color: '#FFFFFF' });
        clicks[clicked.id] = true;
    }
});
```

And so on...

Answer (score 0):

Do the buttons share a common container? Then the following code works:

```
$(container).childElements().each(function(element) {
    $(element).observe('click', function () { … });
    …
});
```

Alternatively, you can also do this:

```
["aa", "bb", "cc"].each(function(element) { … same code … });
```

Comment: does ul count as a container as well?
my buttons are like this

<ul id="buttons">
    <li id = "aa">aa</li>
    <li id = "bb">bb</li>
    <li id = "cc">cc</li>
</ul>

Answer (score 0):

The event handlers can have an argument that will be set to the event target. Then you could reuse the same function:

```
var clickedHandler = function(element) { 
  $(element).addClass("selected");
};
$("aa").observe('click', clickedHandler);
$("bb").observe('click', clickedHandler);
```

You're also in desperate need to CSS styling. Please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266199/prototype-click-mouseover-and-mouseout-cant-work-together#266228) to your previous question, but you could just reuse the pattern for the other events.